# Expresión regular para validar que un número es mayor que 0 y no es null

Tags: regex

Me gustaría obtener una expresión regular que garantice que el número que recibe es superior a 0 y además en ningún caso es null. Este campo puede tener decimales.
¿Cómo hacerlo? Muchas gracias.

Algunos de los intentos que he probado hasta ahora:

```
(^[1-9]+$|[\S\s]+[\S]+)

([0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*(\\.[0-9]+)?|[0]+\\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*)$|^$|\s+

([0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*(\\.[0-9]+)?|[0]+\\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*)$|[\S\s]+[\S]+

"[\S\s]+[\S]+(([0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*(\\.[0-9]+)?|[0]+\\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*)$)"
```

Comment: Hola. Bienvenidx a SOes. Las preguntas van en español y con el código que has intentando hacer. Puedes [edit]

Comment: Gracias por editar la pregunta. ¿En qué lenguaje vas a usar ésto? Con qué datos estás probando y por qué dices que no funcionan? :)

Comment: ¿Podrías dar un poco más de contexto? Creo que una expresión regular no es la herramienta indicada para esto...

Comment: ¿Qué debería hacer con `+10` (signo +), `5 ` (espacios), `2,5` (coma decimal) o `.80` (sin enteros)?

Comment: @Andrew claro, no sería lo adecuado, ya que soluciones existen muchas, pero el OP requiere de utilizar regex y si hay posibilidad de hacerlo.

Comment: @Nacho, ¿te sirvió alguna de las respuestas?

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con la siguiente expresión regular, en donde verifica que el número que recibe la función sea mayor a 0, ya sea con decimales (también en el caso de que si sea negativo con decimal) y que si el valor es **`undefined`** o vacío:

```js
function validarNumero(numero) {
  regex = /^(0*[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?|0+\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*)$/gm;

  if (regex.test(numero) && numero !== undefined && numero !== '') {
    return 'Es mayor a 0';
  } else if (numero === undefined || numero === '') {
    return 'El número no es valido';
  } else {
    return 'No es mayor a 0';
  }
}

console.log(validarNumero('4')); // mayor a 0
console.log(validarNumero('2.1')); // mayor a 0 decimal
console.log(validarNumero('-4')); // menor a 0
console.log(validarNumero('-2.1')); // menor a 0 decimal
console.log(validarNumero('')); // vacío o nulo
console.log(validarNumero()); // undefined
```

Comment: Conviene hacer el chequeo de undefined y vacío primero, para no tener que hacerlo dos veces innecesariamente, y además también evitas la validación con la regex.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es innecesario indicar `[0-9]` cada vez en lugar de simplemente `\d`. Si realmente tengo que utilizar una expresión regular, podría usar esto:

```
^(\d*[1-9]+\d*\.?\d*|\d*\.\d*[1-9]+\d*)$
```

*(Stack Overflow por error muestra en itálicas lo que está entre `*`, lo del medio es un pipe, no una barra `/`)*

Son básicamente dos escenarios:

1. cualquier dígito opcional + `1-9` + cualquier dígito opcional + punto + cualquier dígito opcional
2. cualquier dígito opcional + punto + cualquier dígito opcional + `1-9` + cualquier dígito opcional

Es decir, te aseguras de que haya al menos un número distinto de cero ante o después del punto decimal. Acepta todos estos casos: `1`, `1.1`, `123`, `10`, `10.0`, `10.01`, `10.10`, `010`, `010.11`, `010.01`, `010.000`, `.324`, `.0001000`, `.1000`, `2.120`, `0.230`, `00.1`

Si quieres también aceptar el signo `+` adelante:

```
^\+?(\d*[1-9]+\d*\.?\d*|\d*\.\d*[1-9]+\d*)$
```

Y si quieres aceptar espacios alrededor:

```
^\s*\+?(\d*[1-9]+\d*\.?\d*|\d*\.\d*[1-9]+\d*)\s*$
```